# css element style affecting the parent style

Tags: html, css

I have a `<div>` that contains a `<button>`.  Each have their own classes.  In the styles for each of those classes I specify the `background-color` property.  For some reason the child button over-rides the parent property.

```css
.tab {
  background-color: red;
}

.tab,
button.active {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab">
  <button>My Button</button>
  <button class="active">button 2</button>
</div>
```

Here is a JS Fiddle showing it:

https://jsfiddle.net/jp3kbfwn/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the comma after .tab:

```
.tab button.active {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

With the comma, it is saying to set the background color to blue for both the .tab class and button.active.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're listing your css elements rather than using selectors. Heres what the css should look like.

```
<style>
.tab {
    background-color: red;
}
.tab > button.active {
    background-color: blue;
}
</style>
```

Note how i've added in the `>` selector

Comment: the "active" is actually a class. It might be a different type of active not the mouse event active. It might be a class added via JS when a totally different element is hovered ( this is only an example ). `.tab > button.active` this is how it should be.

Answer (score 0):

The `.tab` element is getting the blue background because you're using a comma between `.tab` and `button.active` when defining their styles.

The comma in this context means apply to both of these elements.